# html5 scorm audio is not playing in android webview but it is playing in ios

Tags: android, html, webview, scorm

```
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView1);
        WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient();
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.setInitialScale(1);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.clearHistory();
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new AudioInterface(this), "AndAud");

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/web/index_SCORM.html"); 
      }
  }
```

I am trying to load the html5 scorm from the asset folder but the sound is not getting played on android. But in ios if I do the same the audio is getting played.
May I know the reason why this is happening?

Comment: Is this specific to SCORM? Is the issue still present if you launch the content as a simple webpage?

Comment: no when i use android web view the html 5 is working fine but the the audio is not getting played but at same time i am trying to call the same html page on my Google chrome browser of android it is getting played properly

Comment: How did you solve this please?